# Comparing 2 sets of lat/longs and if distance between is less than specified amount return a corresponding value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a complicated problem that I have been working on for weeks with no Success, any and all help is much appreciated.

I have 2 pairs of longitude and latitude co-ords,

```
A1:A11418 = lat1  
B1:B11418 = long1  
C1:C11418 = lat1/long1 Corresponding ID to be returned  
D1:D10248 = lat2  
E1:E10248 = long2
F1:F10248 = Return column for ID
```

Columns D, E are in a completely different order than A, B.
I need to match lat/long1 against lat/long2 and compare the distance between and if it is <= the desired distance, output only the ID with the least distance from column C to F.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_click()

Dim ID As Double
Dim Dist, Results, Pre_rslt As Variant
Dim lat1, long1, lat2, long2 As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

j_DO:
Do While j <= 11418             '## lat/long1 (Col D, E) Counter
j = j + 1

i_DO:
    Do While i <= 10248         '## lat/long2 (Col A, B) Counter     
    i = i + 1

    Set lat1 = Range("A2").Offset(i)
    Set long1 = Range("B2").Offset(i)
    Set lat2 = Range("D2").Offset(j)
    Set long2 = Range("E2").Offset(j)

    If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Offset(i).Value) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("B2").Offset(i).Value) = True Then
        i = i + 1
    End If

        earth_radius = 6371    '## GCD START
        PI = 3.14159265
        deg2rad = PI / 180

        dLat = deg2rad * (lat2 - lat1)
        dLon = deg2rad * (long2 - long1)

        a = Sin(dLat / 2) * Sin(dLat / 2) + Cos(deg2rad * lat1) * Cos(deg2rad * lat2) * Sin(dLon / 2) * Sin(dLon / 2)
        c = 2 * WorksheetFunction.Asin(Sqr(a))

        d = earth_radius * c
        Dist = d               '## GCD END

        If Dist <= 1 Then            '## Result filtering
            Results = ID
            Cells(j, 6) = Results
            ID = Range("B2").Offset(i, 1)
            i = 0
            GoTo j_DO
        ElseIf i >= 10248 And Results <> ID Then
            i = 0
            GoTo j_DO
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("F2").Offset(j).Value) = True Then
            GoTo i_DO
        End If
    Loop
Loop

End Sub
```

As it is now, it will return random results and I cannot figure out how to get it to only return the closest result.

P.S  Please forgive my code/explanation I Have only been using VBA for 2-3 weeks and am still very new, thank-you for your help in advance.

Comment: So find the closest lat/lon from lat1 long1 to each lat2/long2 pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed up your code formatting. This works for me.

```
Sub CommandButton2_click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim ID, Results As String
Dim Dist, dist_min As Double
Dim lat1, long1, lat2, long2, dLat, dLong As Double
Dim data1r, data2r As Integer

earth_radius = 6371 'km
Pi = 3.14159265
deg2rad = Pi / 180


For data2r = 2 To 75    '2nd set of lat/lon rows
    dist_min = 2 * earth_radius * Pi    'furthest point on earth
    Results = ""
    For data1r = 2 To 100   '1st set of lat/lon rows
        lat1 = Cells(data1r, 1)
        long1 = Cells(data1r, 2)
        ID = Cells(data1r, 3)
        lat2 = Cells(data2r, 4)
        long2 = Cells(data2r, 5)

        lat1 = lat1 * deg2rad
        long1 = long1 * deg2rad
        lat2 = lat2 * deg2rad
        long2 = long2 * deg2rad
        dLat = Abs(lat2 - lat1)
        dLong = Abs(long2 - long1)

        a = Sin(dLat / 2) ^ 2 + Cos(lat1) * Cos(lat2) * (Sin(dLong) ^ 2)
        c = 2 * WorksheetFunction.Atan2(a ^ 0.5, (1 - a) ^ 0.5)

        d = earth_radius * c
        Dist = d               '## GCD END

        If Dist < dist_min Then
            Results = ID
            dist_min = Dist
            lat = lat1
            lon = long1
        End If

    Next data1r
    Cells(data2r, 6) = Results
Next data2r
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much fr your help this works wonderfully with a few minor tweaks! :)

Comment: You are most welcome! I fortuitously actually have a project that will use the GCD haversine coming up so good primer for that.

Comment: hello again, I have been enjoying tinkering with your changes trying to reverse engineer it to understand for myself what I was doing wrong. I was wondering what these lines do as I cannot work it out;  
lat = lat1  
    long = long1

As far as I can see there is not even another mention to "lat" or "lon" in any other lines of the code once again thank you for your help

Comment: Good catch. They do nothing besides record the lat and lon of the point. When doing this type of "searching" code I tend to pull out everything that I might need. In this case I didn't go back and remove the extraneous lines. I tried to clean up your code, but had trouble so started from scratch. Key is when/where you reset the distance.